# Proving a FOL sentence using resolution

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I need to prove this is true using resolution.

**Every horse can outrun every dog.**

**Some greyhounds can outrun every rabbit.**

**Show that every horse can outrun every rabbit.**

So my FOL version of this is the following.

$\forall x \forall y (horse(x) \land dog(y) \to outrun (x, y))$

$\exists y (greyhound(y) \land \forall z (rabbit(z) \to outrun (y, z)))$

$\forall y (greyhound(y) \to dog(y))$

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (outrun(x, y) \land outrun(y, z) \to outrun(x, z))$

conclusion:

$\forall x \forall y (horse(x) \land rabbit(y) \to outrun(x, y))$

I negated the conclusion and then converted this to clausal form which looks like this.

$\{\neg horse(x), \neg dog(y), outrun(x, y)\}$

$\{greyhound(a), \neg rabbit(z)\}$

$\{greyhound(a), outrun(a, z)\}$

$\{\neg greyhound(y), dog(y)\}$

$\{\neg outrun(x, y), \neg outrun(y, z), outrun(x, z)\}$

$\{horse(a), rabbit(b), \neg outrun(a, b)\}$

The problem is that the resolution proof is taking awhile and I'm not sure my clausal form is correct. I don't want to waste time with this proof if I'm never going to derive the empty clause. So is my clausal form incorrect or am I doing something wrong with my resolution proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the resolution proof is taking awhile and I'm not sure my clausal form is correct. I don't want to waste time with this proof if I'm never going to derive the empty clause. So is my clausal form incorrect or am I doing something wrong with my resolution proof?

I can't comment on whether you are doing anything else wrong, but as you suspect, your causal forms are incorrect and that is not a good start.   You've mostly got it, but there were a few mistakes.   Keep trying.

Here is what you should use, and it can be resolved to emptiness.

$$\begin{align}1.~&\{\neg horse(x), \neg dog(y), outrun(x, y)\}\\2.~&\{greyhound(a)\}\\3.~&\{\neg rabbit(z), outrun(a,z)\}\\4.~&\{\neg greyhound(y), dog(y)\}\\5.~&\{\neg outrun(x, y), \neg outrun(y, z), outrun(x, z)\}\\6.~&\{horse(c)\}\\7.~&\{rabbit(b)\}\\8.~&\{\neg outrun(c, b)\}\end{align}$$

---

Here's where you went wrong (and right).

> **Every horse can outrun every dog.**
>
> $\forall x \forall y (horse(x) \land dog(y) \to outrun (x, y))$
>
> $\{\neg horse(x), \neg dog(y), outrun(x, y)\}$

That's okay.

---

> **Some greyhounds can outrun every rabbit.**
>
> $\exists y (greyhound(y) \land \forall z (rabbit(z) \to outrun (y, z)))$
>
> $\{greyhound(a), \neg rabbit(z)\}$
>
> $\{greyhound(a), outrun(a, z)\}$

No, clauses are seperated by the conjunction.   Witness that there is a greyhound.   Also, anything can be outrun by that witness if it is a rabbit.

$\{greyhound(a)\} \\ \{\neg rabbit(z), outrun(a,z)\}$

---

> $\forall y (greyhound(y) \to dog(y))$
>
> $\{\neg greyhound(a), dog(y)\}$

Good work realising you need to add this analytical consequence.
  But, it is not the case that *everything* is a dog if witness $a$ is a greyhound.

The analytical consequence should either be included as a universal clause, $\{\neg greyhound(y), dog(y)\}$, or skip a step to intantiate it to the witness $\{\neg greyhound(a), dog(a)\}$.   One or the other must be used; don't be half-hearted about it.   And since you left the next as a universal, for consistency you should do so here too.

$\{\neg greyhound(y), dog(y)\}$

---

> $\forall x \forall y \forall z (outrun(x, y) \land outrun(y, z) \to outrun(x, z))$
>
> $\{\neg outrun(x, y), \neg outrun(y, z), outrun(x, z)\}$

Good; again you recognised the need to include transitivity of outrun as an analytical consequence.

---

> **Show that every horse can outrun every rabbit.**
>
> conclusion: $\forall x \forall y (horse(x) \land rabbit(y) \to outrun(x, y))$
>
> I negated the conclusion and then converted this to clausal form which looks like this.
>
> $\{horse(a), rabbit(b), \neg outrun(a, b)\}$

That is the correct approach, however, the technique is awry.   Now, you have already instantiated witness $a$ (and it is a greyhound), so you cannot use it here.   You *must* use new terms to witness different existentials.   Additionally the negation of a conditional is a conjunction, vis: $\exists x \exists y~(horse(x) \land rabbit(y) \land\neg outrun(x, y))$, so that forms three witnessed clauses:

$\{horse(c)\}, \{rabbit(b)\}, \{\neg outrun(c, b)\}$

---

Overall, a commendable effort, but some practice is needed handling existential instances.

Carry on.

Comment: It should be noted there was a typo in my question. In my clausal form I actually did have $\{\neg greyhound(y), dog(y)\}$ and I accidentally said "a" when I typed in into the question here.